# Custom QDropAction Label?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

In my project, I want the user to be able to drag and drop a file onto my program and have it open as if they "browsed" for the file.

Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasUrls())
    {
        if(event->mimeData()->urls().size() == 1)
        {
            QFileInfo inputFile = event->mimeData()->urls().at(0).toLocalFile();
            if(inputFile.suffix() == "dat")
            {
                event->acceptProposedAction();
            }
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event)
{
    inputPath = event->mimeData()->urls().at(0).toLocalFile();
    on_actionOpen_Savegame_triggered();
}
```

Everything works as I need it to, except the drop action says "Copy" when the user is about to drop the file.

[image]

I can change the QDropAction to either Copy, Move, Link, or Ignore, but not Open... Is there anyway I can either remove the text saying "Copy" or just change it to say "Open"

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there isn't a way to change the text that appears when performing a drag-and-drop through Qt (from either the sending or the receiving end of the drag-n-drop).

On the receiving end of the drag-and-drop you're limited to accepting one of the possible `Qt::DropAction` values present in `event->possibleActions()` (and then I believe it's up to the OS to interpret this action in whatever way it wants.  Looking at the [related Windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/664ke246.aspx) for the drag enter event I see a similar story: the only possible response for this event is to select a `DROPEFFECT`).  I wish there was clear Qt documentation on this, but I haven't been able to locate it.

So, like you mentioned, you can change the text to read either 'Copy', 'Move', 'Link', or 'Ignore', but nothing more.